# Why doesn't YAML alias work unless I use flow style?

Tags: yaml

If you run this YAML 1.1

```
- &first {'first': ['description', ['aliases'], ["Explanatory sentences ", "go here."]]}
- *first
- &second 'second':
    - 'description'
    - ['aliases']
    -
        - "Explanatory sentences "
        - "go here."
- *second
```

through [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com), you get this:

```
--- 
- 
  first: 
    - description
    - 
      - aliases
    - 
      - "Explanatory sentences "
      - "go here."
- 
  first: 
    - description
    - 
      - aliases
    - 
      - "Explanatory sentences "
      - "go here."
- 
  second: 
    - description
    - 
      - aliases
    - 
      - "Explanatory sentences "
      - "go here."
- second
```

Notice that the `first` group is repeated twice, while the `second` group is only shown in full once, with just the name where the repeated block should be.  The `first` group and the `second` group have exactly the same data - the only difference is the layout.  Why doesn't the alias work properly for the `second` group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the &anchor has very high precedence.  I tried this

```
- &first 'first': ['description', ['aliases'], ["Explanatory sentences ", "go here."]]
- *first
```

Rather than this:

```
- &first {'first': ['description', ['aliases'], ["Explanatory sentences ", "go here."]]}
- *first
```

And suddenly it behaved the same way as the `second` group.  So it appears that unless you explicitly include the `'first'` in a larger node, the `&first` anchor attaches to just the `'first'` string and nothing else.